# Navigation bar disappeared after changing to RelativeLayout

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-layout, layout

my AndroidStudio is using as a default layout the ConstraintLayout and I changed it in the XML code into RelativeLayout. At the end I placed again all the UI were I needed.
In the other activities the layouts are still the ConstraintLayout. My plan is to change those once also to RelativeLayout later.

My problem after the change is, that the Navigation bar from Android has disappeared. See picture.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WKCSo.png)

My code from the XML is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#FFFFFF"
tools:context=".MainActivity">


<EditText
    android:id="@+id/passwordField"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:hint="@string/password"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="numberPassword"
     />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:text="@string/login"
    android:textSize="36sp"
    />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/logInButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_below="@id/checkBox"
    android:onClick="logIn"
    android:text="@string/log_in"
     />

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkBox"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_below="@id/passwordField"
    android:onClick="showPassword"
    android:text="@string/show_password"
    />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/logInButton"
    android:onClick="createNewAccount"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:text="@string/create_account"
     />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textForgotPassword"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:onClick="forgotPassword"
    android:text="@string/forgot_the_password_click_here" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Could someone tell me please what I have done wrong?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Why do you want to use Relative when there is a constraint layout available which has more features and easy to use stuff.

Comment: I know maybe this is not a reason why I prefer the RelativeLayout, but for me its easier to set the UI and have them in the same position also for more android devices.

Comment: I would highly recommend to adopt constraint layout it is far more easily maintained with huge benefits across different devices

Comment: @AbdulWaheed thank you very much for your recommendation! I will try it. Could you tell me please also if its possible to keep all the UI in the same position for every device?

Comment: yes this is possible indeen that is why I am suggesting you to use constraint layout. give it try :)